# What is there to be done about all those old questions?

Tags: discussion

Now and again, an old question will make its way up onto the homepage... like, *really* old.

[How do I enroll devices while "Can enable remote management" is disabled?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36786/how-do-i-enroll-devices-while-can-enable-remote-management-is-disabled) was bumped just a few minutes ago, and is from 2012.

Since technology is changing a lot (unlike a lot of other SE topics), what can we do about this? These questions are very difficult to answer and are nearly uneditable because of how different iOS 4 and MobileMe were from iOS 11 and iCloud.